# Why does this FutureTask cause my program to hang forever?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and trying to understand how FutureTasks work. In my particular case I'm trying to spawn a thread (FutureTask) to execute something. I don't actually care about its response; I just want it to execute asynchronously. I've got that much working with the following test code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadInstance();
        FutureTask<Boolean> asynch = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    //  wait for 5 seconds to simulate activity
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                System.out.println("Complete");
                return true;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Started");
        exService.execute(asynch);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it prints "Started" to the console, then five seconds later prints "Complete" like I would expect. However... the program just hangs indefinitely at that point. I was assuming that because the call() method had completed that the program would be smart enough to quit at that point, but apparently it keeps that thread alive forever? How do I get it to run the task once and then quit?

Comment: The executor service is using non-daemon threads which is preventing the JVM from terminating. Try shutting down the service

Comment: Why does everyone do comments instead of answers around here? That worked perfectly; that was the missing link. Write that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cause it was a thought which I wanted to verify before making a complete *** of myself (like usual ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The executor service is using non-daemon threads which is preventing the JVM from terminating, try shutting down the service once you have completed with it...

```
    System.out.println("Started");
    exService.execute(asynch);
    exService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Good night sweet prince...");
```

This will cause the service to wait until all currently running tasks have completed, but won't accept any new ones to be added...